# WordPress displaying custom post type posts by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, post

I have a custom post type `logie` and it has a custom taxonomy with now 3 options.

My goals is to display every post per taxonomy in a different bootstrap row like this:

Taxonomy title 1

Post Post Post

Taxonomy title 2

Post Post Post

Taxonomy title 3

Post Post Post

So every `Post` is a col and the title and posts are in a row

This is what my code looks like now. The titles work but to get the posts it is a bit tricky. I get no errors which is kinda annoying...

```
<div class="container-full">
        <?php foreach ($cat as $catVal):
              $postArg = array('post_type'=>'logie','posts_per_page'=>-1,'order'=>'desc',
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'logietype',
                                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                                        'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                    )
                            ));

            $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
            global $post;
        ?>
            <div class="row">
               <h2><?php echo $catVal->name; ?></h2>
                <?php if($getPost->have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post(): ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Anyone can help me out thanks a lot!!

Comment: `new wp_query` should be `new WP_Query`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simplier argument query:

```
$postArg = array(
  'post_type'=>'logie',
  'posts_per_page'=>-1,
  'order'=>'desc',
  'logietype' => $catVal->term_id
);
```

By the way, I suggest to use the more native

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

which can be hooked if needed.